# Setting the output folder for workspace and project files in Gradle Idea plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Is there a way to control where the .iws and .ipr files get generated?  For instance, I have a project that is setup like this:

```
masterProj
  |
  +- devScripts
  +- subProj1
  +- subProj2
  +- subProjX
```

Where the `devScripts` folder contains all our common build related stuff plus some code to boot-strap our Java apps.  Currently it generates Eclipse projects, but I'd like to add the ability to generate IntelliJ projects as well.  When we create our Eclipse workspaces we do that at the `masterProj` level, then import the project folders, including `devScripts`, under that. But if I run the gradle command in the `devScripts` folder for IntelliJ it places the .iws and .ipr files under `devScripts`, but it really should be one folder up.

What I'd like to end up with is something like:

```
masterProj
 masterProj.iws
 masterProj.ipr
  |
  +- devScripts
      devScritps.iml
  +- subProj1
      subProj1.iml
  +- subProj2
      subProj2.iml
  +- subProjX
      subProjX.iml
```

Comment: Why do you need to generate IntelliJ IDEA files for a Gradle project? IDE will automatically setup project based on the Gradle configuration, so it should not be needed to specifically generate IDE configuration files.

Comment: @Andrey We have a very automated setup and build process, and an internally-built DI framework in Java and NodeJS.  Running the app local in a manual way is painful to impossible, hence the local Dev automation.  The scripts currently support Eclipse and VSCode, but I have had requests to add IntelliJ as well.  Phase 1 is to get the project files build, Phase 2 is to build the IntelliJ equivalent of the Eclipse launcher. This is a company-wide framework developed over many years by people other than myself that would not be easy to retire.

Comment: I haven't found any such options in [Gradle idea plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html). Feel free to file a request for a feature to Gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle